# How to pass an MPI communicator from python to C via cython?

Tags: python, c, mpi, cython, mpi4py

I am trying to wrap a C function taking an `MPI_Comm` communicator handle as a parameter via cython. As a result, I want to be able to call the function from python, passing it an `mpi4py.MPI.Comm` object. What I am wondering is, how to make the conversion from `mpi4py.MPI.Comm` to `MPI_Comm`.

To demonstrate, I use a simple "Hello World!"-type function:

`helloworld.h`:

```c
#ifndef HELLOWORLD
#define HELLOWORLD
#include <mpi.h>

void sayhello(MPI_Comm comm);

#endif
```

`helloworld.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "helloworld.h"

void sayhello(MPI_Comm comm){
    int size, rank;
    MPI_Comm_size(comm, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &rank);
    printf("Hello, World! "
           "I am process %d of %d.\n",
           rank, size);
}
```

I now want to call this function from python like this:

`from_python.py`:

```python
import mpi4py
import helloworld_wrap

helloworld_wrap.py_sayhello(mpi4py.MPI.COMM_WORLD)
```

Meaning that `mpirun -np 4 python2 from_python.py` is supposed to give something like:

> Hello, World! I am process 0 of 4.
>   Hello, World! I am process 1 of 4.
>   Hello, World! I am process 2 of 4.
>   Hello, World! I am process 3 of 4.

But if I try to achieve this via cython like this:

`helloworld_wrap.pyx`:

```python
cimport mpi4py.MPI as MPI
cimport mpi4py.libmpi as libmpi

cdef extern from "helloworld.h":
   void sayhello(libmpi.MPI_Comm comm)

def py_sayhello(MPI.Comm comm):
    sayhello(comm)
```

and:

`setup.py`:

```python
import os
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

mpi_compile_args = os.popen("mpicc --showme:compile").read().strip().split(' ')
mpi_link_args    = os.popen("mpicc --showme:link").read().strip().split(' ')

ext_modules=[
    Extension("helloworld_wrap",
              sources            = ["helloworld_wrap.pyx", "helloworld.c"],
              language           = 'c',
              extra_compile_args = mpi_compile_args,
              extra_link_args    = mpi_link_args,
          )
]

setup(
  name = "helloworld_wrap",
  cmdclass = {"build_ext": build_ext},
  ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

I get the following error message:

> helloworld_wrap.pyx:8:13: Cannot convert Python object to 'MPI_Comm'

indicating that `mpi4py.MPI.Comm` can't be converted into an `MPI_Comm`. So how can I convert the `mpi4py.MPI.Comm` into an `MPI_Comm` in order to get my wrapper to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conversion is rather simple, as a `mpi4py.MPI.Comm`-object internally stores an `MPI_Comm` handle as member `ob_mpi`<sup>1</sup>. Therefore, if one changes the last line of `helloworld_wrap.pyx` to pass `comm.ob_mpi` instead of `comm`, the module compiles and works as intended:

`helloworld_wrap.pyx`:

```python
cimport mpi4py.MPI as MPI
cimport mpi4py.libmpi as libmpi

cdef extern from "helloworld.h":
   void sayhello(libmpi.MPI_Comm comm)

def py_sayhello(MPI.Comm comm):
    sayhello(comm.ob_mpi)
```

Surprisingly, I did not find any documentation for this but only realized this when studying the [sources of `mpi4py.MPI.Comm`](https://bitbucket.org/mpi4py/mpi4py/src/18c52a947443765dea0adaee0b702c044d9f150c/src/mpi4py/MPI/Comm.pyx?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#Comm.pyx-37). I am not sure, if this is the intended way to handle this, but I could not get it to work otherwise.

---

<sup>1</sup> In fact, most, if not all objects in `mpi4py.MPI` that model a corresponding MPI handle in C, hold a corresponding handle as member `ob_mpi`.

Comment: It is also my experience that `mpi4py` is vastly under-documented and one is often required to look into the source to figure out how things work.

Comment: @Zulan I also got that feeling. I figured, I'd at least document this here.