# Sharing an MPI communicator using pybind11

Tags: python, c++, mpi, pybind11

Suppose that I have created a wrapper around an MPI communicator:

```
class Communicator {
   public:
      Communicator() : comm(MPI_COMM_WORLD) {}

      Communicator(int const color, int const key) {
        MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, color, key, &comm);
      }

      Communicator(MPI_Comm comm) : comm(comm) {}

      MPI_Comm GetComm() const { return comm; }
    private:
      MPI_Comm comm;
};
```

I would like to use pybind11 to create a python wrapper around this object that looks something like this:

```
void CommunicatorWrapper(pybind11::module &m) {
   py::class_<Communicator, std::shared_ptr<Communicator> > commWrap(m, "Communicator");

   commWrap.def(py::init( []() { return new Communicator(); } ));
   commWrap.def(py::init( [](int const color, int const key) { return new Communicator(color, key); } ));
   commWrap.def(py::init( [](MPI_Comm comm) { return new Communicator(comm); } ));
   commWrap.def("GetComm", &Communicator::GetComm);
}
```

However, I'd like the `MPI_Comm` type that python sees to be `mpi4py.MPI.Comm`.  Is this possible? If so, how?

The above (naive) implementation results in the following behavior:

```
comm = Communicator(MPI.COMM_WORLD)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: __init__(): incompatible constructor arguments. The following argument types are supported:
1. Communicator()
2. Communicator(arg0: int, arg1: int)
3. Communicator(arg0: int)
```

and

```
comm = Communicator()
print(comm.GetComm())
```

prints `-2080374784`.  This behavior makes sense given what `MPI_Comm` is but is obviously not the functionality I need.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51557135/how-to-pass-an-mpi-communicator-from-python-to-c-via-cython seems relevant but the ob_mpi object does not seems to actually exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by changing the wrapper to

```
#include <mpi4py/mpi4py.h>

pybind11::handle CallGetComm(Communicator *comm) {
    const int rc = import_mpi4py();
    return pybind11::handle(PyMPIComm_New(comm->GetComm()));;
}

void CommunicatorWrapper(pybind11::module &m) {
   py::class_<Communicator, std::shared_ptr<Communicator> > commWrap(m, "Communicator");

   commWrap.def(py::init( []() { return new Communicator(); } ));
   commWrap.def(py::init( [](int const color, int const key) { return new Communicator(color, key); } ));
   commWrap.def(py::init( [](pybind11::handle const& comm) {
     const int rc = import_mpi4py();
     assert(rc==0);
     return new Communicator(*PyMPIComm_Get(comm.ptr()));
    } ));
   commWrap.def("GetComm", &CallGetComm);
}
```