# How to pass MPI communicator handle from Python to C?

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

Based on [How to pass an MPI communicator from python to C via cython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51557135/how-to-pass-an-mpi-communicator-from-python-to-c-via-cython), the MPI communicator handle is stored in `ob_mpi`. However, when running the following Python code snippet:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

world_comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
world_size = world_comm.Get_size()
world_rank = world_comm.Get_rank()

block_size = 4
blocks = int(world_size / block_size)

color = int(world_rank / block_size)
key = int(world_rank % block_size)

block_comm = world_comm.Split(color, key)

print(block_comm.ob_mpi)
```

It returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(block_comm.ob_mpi)
AttributeError: 'mpi4py.MPI.Intracomm' object has no attribute 'ob_mpi'
```

Any idea why is that?

Comment: the snippet is python and not cython.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet: I see - thanks for noticing it. Do you know how can we retrieve the underlying MPI communicator handle from `block_comm` in Python though? I would like to pass it to a C function.

Comment: I'd keep it simple and write a wrapper in cython just like in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @GillesGouaillardet - after digging a bit further on `mpi4py`, one can actually get the handle of the MPI communicator by calling `MPI._addressof(block_comm)`.